# Convert underlined text to highlighted text in Google Docs

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs

I'd like to write a script to **highlight** any word in a google doc that is underlined. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35106984/google-script-how-to-highlight-a-group-of-words) is the closest thing I could find.

(Note - in the last line milk would be yellow, not grey.)

**Example**

I went to the store and bought m̲i̲l̲k̲ and eggs.

*would change to this:*

I went to the store and bought `milk` and eggs.

Comment: May be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/a/27974206/555121